# WebRequest BeginGetRequestStream and BeginGetResponse do not fire their callbacks

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, httpwebrequest

I have a PHP web service using JSON that I need to post requests to from a Silverlight application. I had used the `HttpWebRequest` class before, in a regular C# application and it worked flawlessly. In my Silverlight application, however, the callbacks for the `BeginGetRequestStream` and `BeginGetResponse` methods are not getting called.

I tried testing it out in about every way without success. Note that the data I am sending is not long - just a 32 character string most of the time. I checked if the callbacks were getting called at all, and they weren't being called. Here is my code:

```
    public void Request(Command cmd, Dictionary<string, string> data)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> fullRequest = new Dictionary<string,object>();
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";                 

                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(writer, fullRequest);
                string query = "query=" + writer.ToString();

                request.ContentLength = query.Length;
                request.ContentType = "text/json";
                _queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<Command, string>(cmd, query));
                request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);

public void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult target)
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)target.AsyncState;

            Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(target);
            string postData = "";
            //not sure why I have to do this. in the Silverlight documentation
            //Queue<> is supposed to have the SyncRoot property
            //but  I get an error if I just try _queue.SyncRoot
            lock ((_queue as ICollection).SyncRoot)
            {
                postData = _queue.Dequeue().Value;

            }
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
            postStream.Close();
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
        }


 public void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;            
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();            
            streamResponse.Close();
            streamRead.Close();            
            response.Close();           
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            Dictionary<string, object> responseData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            responseData = (Dictionary<string, object>)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(responseString), typeof(Dictionary<string, object>));
            if (_data.ContainsKey(responseData["key"] as string))
            {
                _data[responseData["key"] as string] = responseData;
            }
            else
            {
                _data.Add(responseData["key"] as string, responseData);
            }
```

I also tried this:

```
IAsyncResult resultRequest = request.BeginGetRequestStream(null, null) as IAsyncResult;
Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(resultRequest );
```

To get the stream synchronously (yes, bad style, I just wanted to see if it will work). No success .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that the JsonSerializer is returning an empty string, so your content length is being set to 0, and therefore the callback isnt being called? Since you do the BeginGetResponse() inside the request stream callback, it totally blocks your application. Try changing verb to GET and remove the entity and see if you get a callback. Or try setting the query as a dummy string that you control.

Comment: Thanks. The json string is fine, I had checked if it is empty and used a dummy. I tried using GET instead of POST as you suggested and I still don't get a callback.

Comment: Can you distill your silverlight application down to an essential piece that demonstrates the behavior you are seeing? From the snippets itself, I dont see anything wrong.

Comment: Yes, here is a link to the most bare bones state that I could bring it:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15924222/HttpWebRequestMalfunction.rar
I mean essentially, this is the state of the full application at the moment - just the httprequest code and some data handling for when a response is received (which, since I am not receiving, I stripped off). I tested the code against my web service and again I did not get a callback. I have to note though that I tried the WebClient and it actually worked - it's event fired, I got response to my query.